# SMTP settings work from localhost but on server it doesn't with PHPMailer

Tags: email, yii, phpmailer

This is the issue what i am facing

**Localhost**

- Test mail with SMTP settings work
- New user creation mail using the above smtp settings work

**Server**

- Test mail with SMTP settings work
- New user creation mail using the above smtp settings doesn't work

I echoed the mail smtp settings in both the cases and they are exactly same. The error i am getting is

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)SMTP Connect()
>   failed.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

---

I further debug it. The behavior turns out to be wierd

```
if (isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        if (UserUtil::validateAndSaveUserData($model, $_POST))
        {
                $mailer   = new UiMailer();
                $mailer->setFrom('fromAddress', 'fromName');
                $mailer->setTo('toaddress');
                $mailer->setSubject('Test subject');
                $mailer->setBody('Test Body');
                $mailer->Mailer = 'smtp';
                $mailer->Username = 'username';
                $mailer->Password = 'password';
                $mailer->Host     = 'host';
                $mailer->Port     = 25;
                $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
                $status         = $mailer->send() ? true : false;
                if($status == true)
                {
                    print "Sucess";
                }
                else
                {
                    print $mailer->ErrorInfo . "</br>";
                    print "Failuere";
                }
                exit;
        }
    }
```

If i comment the call if (UserUtil::validateAndSaveUserData($model, $_POST)), it works fine. In the function i am validating and saving models using Yii framework. I further debug the function. I have the following relation in the system

- User has one person
- User has one address

So in the above call, if i comment the address part which $model->address->attributes or $model->address->validate or $model->address->save(), it works fine. The save functionality for address works fine. There are no issues related to it.

Comment: You could start with [the docs on this subject](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). Sounds like a DNS problem.

Comment: Its an issue with captcha rule to check for GD requirements which is breaking the flow. I don't understand the reason properly why? That is not being called when i am sending test email. Now at least i can proceed.